# Creating Frameworks in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks

In order to create framework in iOS, I am following below link.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios#comments

I am doing the same way as mentioned but it doesn't create the any framework folder on Desktop. In the new target created, I am adding below script. Any help appreciated

Comment: When you build the framework, what target do you have selected?

Comment: from the link, I can see, first I should build the library that I have added it to the project and secondly, buidling the target that I have added as new Aggregate to the project

Comment: When you build, build the framework (the red target-looking thing) in the original project.